# How do I build a tree structure with C#?

Tags: c#, tree

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to build a tree from basically three dictionaries.

It goes like this:

- Project > Seasons > Episodes

So basically I have a list of projects, then each project can have one or more seasons, and then each season can have one or more episodes.

How would I go about creating a tree structure for this so that I can send it back as a JSON?

I'd really appreciate any help as I'm struggling with this.

This is what I started with:

```
//projects
        var projectsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var ProjectSearchResult = new ProjectSearchResultController();
        var ProjectSearchCriteria = new GBLProjectSearchCriteria
        {
                ProjectName = projectName, SearchType = "P", QueryString = "?ProjectId="
        };
        var GBLProjectSearchResultListData = ProjectSearchResult.GetProjectSearchResultList(ProjectSearchCriteria);
        foreach (GBLProjectSearchResult item in GBLProjectSearchResultListData)
        {
            projectsDictionary.Add(item.Id, item.Title);
        }
        foreach (var project in projectsDictionary)
        {
            //seasons
            var seasonsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            var SeasonSearchResult = new ProjectSearchResultController();
            var SeasonSearchCriteria = new GBLProjectSearchCriteria
            {
                    Id = project.Key, ProjectName = projectName, SearchType = "S", QueryString = "?ProjectId=" + projectId + "&SeasonId=",
            };
            var GBLSeasonSearchResultListData = SeasonSearchResult.GetProjectSearchResultList(SeasonSearchCriteria);
            foreach (GBLProjectSearchResult item in GBLSeasonSearchResultListData)
            {
                seasonsDictionary.Add(item.Id, item.Title);
            }
            foreach (var season in seasonsDictionary)
            {
                //episodes
                var episodesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                var episodeSearchResult = new ProjectSearchResultController();
                var episodeSearchCriteria = new GBLProjectSearchCriteria
                {
                        Id = season.Key, ProjectName = projectName, SearchType = "E", QueryString = "?ProjectId=" + projectId + "&SeasonId=" + seasonId + "&EpisodeId=",
                };
                var GBLEpisodeSearchResultListData = episodeSearchResult.GetProjectSearchResultList(episodeSearchCriteria);
                foreach (GBLProjectSearchResult item in GBLEpisodeSearchResultListData)
                {
                    episodesDictionary.Add(item.Id, item.Title);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is not working with your implementation?

Comment: You mean to create objects in Tree Structure?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to convert what I have to a tree structure but I'm unsure on how to do it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current approach will not work
May be this will help you
Create three Classes named

Project
Seasons
Episodes

```
public class Episodes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Seasons
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<Episodes> { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<Seasons> { get; set; }
}
```

Just Create a new list of Project at the top of your method

```
IList<Project> projectList = new List<Project>();
```

After that while filling up the data do like this

```
IList<Project> projectList = new List<Project>();
var ProjectSearchResult = new ProjectSearchResultController();
var ProjectSearchCriteria = new GBLProjectSearchCriteria
{
        ProjectName = projectName, SearchType = "P", QueryString = "?ProjectId="
};
var GBLProjectSearchResultListData = ProjectSearchResult.GetProjectSearchResultList(ProjectSearchCriteria);
foreach (GBLProjectSearchResult item in GBLProjectSearchResultListData)
{
    Project project = new Project();
    project.Id = item.Id;
    project.Title = item.Title;
    projectList.Add(project);
}
foreach (var project in projectList)
{
    //seasons
    project.Seasons = new List<Seasons>();
    var SeasonSearchResult = new ProjectSearchResultController();
    var SeasonSearchCriteria = new GBLProjectSearchCriteria
    {
            Id = project.Key, ProjectName = projectName, SearchType = "S", QueryString = "?ProjectId=" + projectId + "&SeasonId=",
    };
    var GBLSeasonSearchResultListData = SeasonSearchResult.GetProjectSearchResultList(SeasonSearchCriteria);
    foreach (GBLProjectSearchResult item in GBLSeasonSearchResultListData)
    {
        Seasons season = new Seasons();
        season.Id = item.Id;
        season.Title = item.Title;
        project.Seasons.Add(season);
    }
    foreach (var season in project.Seasons)
    {
        //episodes
        season.Episodes = new List<Episodes>();
        var episodeSearchResult = new ProjectSearchResultController();
        var episodeSearchCriteria = new GBLProjectSearchCriteria
        {
                Id = season.Key, ProjectName = projectName, SearchType = "E", QueryString = "?ProjectId=" + projectId + "&SeasonId=" + seasonId + "&EpisodeId=",
        };
        var GBLEpisodeSearchResultListData = episodeSearchResult.GetProjectSearchResultList(episodeSearchCriteria);
        foreach (GBLProjectSearchResult item in GBLEpisodeSearchResultListData)
        {
            Episodes episode = new Episodes();
            episode.Id = item.Id;
            episode.Title = item.Title;
            season.Episodes.Add(episode);
        }
    }
}
```

Or May be instead of writing so much of code you can also use LINQ or Lambda Expressions

For Data Serilization to JSON Format

You can create a Extension Method:

```
    public static string ToJson<T>(this T objectToBeConverted, Func<T, object> filter)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(filter(objectToBeConverted));
    }
```

Filter can be created like this:

```
Func<IList<Project>, object> filter =
                new Func<IList<Project>, object>(projects => projects.Select(project => new { project.Id, project.Title }));
```

Comment: I'm getting a "cannot resolve symbol "episodes" at the very end: project.seasons.episodes.Add(episode);

Comment: A copy paste error, Changed project.Seasons.Episodes.Add(episode); to seasons.Episodes.Add(episode); Please make the changes and check it